# Cannot link my extension's popup(html file) and javascript file using onclick()

Tags: javascript, extension-methods

I cannot link my extension's HTML file with JS.The output I was expecting was that h4 line would change into "not skipper".
I have been trying `onclick` function, I read that I needed to use `.addEventListener()` but I couldn't make it work.

The webpage works when I test it as an actual webpage using live server but fails when i try to use it in an extension.

I wanted to know how to correct my `onclick()` mistake and how to use `.addEventListener()` for this code
Manifest.json file

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Skipper",
"version": "1.0",


"description": "Does something",
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "stuff/potato.jpg",
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_title": "Skipper!"
},
"icons": {
  "48": "stuff/potato.jpg"
},
"permissions": [
  "activeTab"
 ],


"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [""http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "js": ["pop.js"]
  }
  ]


 }
```

This is my extension's HTML which is in proper directory

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Skipper</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4 id="help">Skipper</h4>
    <button onclick="func()">Reload</button>
</body>
<script src="pop.js"></script>
</html>
```

This is my JS file

```
function func()
{
    var change=document.getElementById("line").innerHTML="not skipper";
    return change;
}
```